# Как переместить письмо в корзину с помощью MailKit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email, mailkit

Пишу свой почтовый клиент на с# использую MailKit.
Удаляю письмо из папки при помощи:

```
 await folder.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadWrite, сt);
 await folder.AddFlagsAsync(id, MessageFlags.Deleted, true, ct);
```

Но оно перемещается не в корзину, а вообще удаляется с сервера. Кто-нибудь знает, как это обойти? (Почтовый ящик gmail)

Comment: Попробуйте перемещать письмо в папку, а не помечать на удаление. Папку корзины можете взять через `ImapClient.GetFolder (SpecialFolder.Trash)`, правда не все сервера поддерживают такое (зовется `SPECIAL-USE`), и тут стоит проверять возможность через `if (ImapClient.Capabilities.HasFlag (ImapCapabilities.SpecialUse))`, если все ок, папку получили, переносите письмо в корзину.